# Why is the HTTP response code not available in the PHP $_SERVER variable?

Tags: php, http-headers

Why is the HTTP response code (or the first line of the HTTP response header) not available in the PHP [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variable array?

Is it a limitation on the way server technology works? A limitation with PHP? With the HTTP protocol? Or maybe I'd be completely NUTS to ever want the HTTP response code? ;)

In my case, I'm working with Apache2.

Just curious.

**EDIT 1:** I'm inquiring about the equivalent of `%>s` ([the status of the LAST request](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats)) used by [Apache's LogFormat directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformat) **before** the server response is sent.

**EDIT 2:** The answers make perfect sense, but the question remains, why can't I get my server's internal *working* response code? If I set an `ErrorDocument 403 /index.php`, I can access the response code with `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS']`. Isn't there an easier way? I'm guessing not. I still learned a lot from your answers, however. It makes sense.

There's also [apache_response_headers()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-response-headers.php), but still no love for the working response code/first line.

Comment: You're building the response; the code your server sends *back* is the response code. What do you need it for on the server? Streams?

Comment: Tell me, when exactly you want to get the response code? Before or after the response has been sent?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php

Comment: @NullPointer Yes, but somehow I think it's not what the OP wants. )

Comment: $_SERVER contains server variables in REQUEST(incoming) headers. HTTP status code is one of the RESPONSE(outgoing) headers :) Don't rephrase your question, you'll get nowhere.

Comment: Although uncommon, whatever response code you send from your script may get later changed before being sent to the client, because the webserver may ultimately pass your output onto another response handler.

Comment: I'm learning! Keep the constructive comments coming! I think I get it.

Comment: The only times a response header is going to be useful is if you're manipulating it internally between a request/response (and need to know what it is "downstream" before you initiate sending the headers/output), or if your server is connecting to another computer and that server (now a client with it's own request) needs to know what the other server has returned as a response code.

Comment: The behaviour is constrained by the CGI protocol, which PHP is largely based on. Incoming request data is shoveled into `HTTP_*` environment variables. And env vars are mostly a one-way ticket, input to the CGI (or here PHP) process. The response headers (and thus the `Status:` code or `HTTP/1.x NNN` head are supposed to be written to the stdout CGI channel, which then is evaluated by the webserver.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the HTTP response is something that is sent to the client, and you can change it within your PHP using the `header` function.  It's not something that is automatic within your PHP and would be handled by the server (ie apache) before it would be given over to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER contains all data of the http request, headers and also other info like the path of current file. But not response, your script is meant to create the response, not access it.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set it with header function, status code will always be `200` for successful responses and in case of fatal error, php may change it to `500` (Internal Server Error).

Almost every other status is handled by the webserver without passing thee request to your script.

Comment: DO you know if 400 is sometimes handled by apache without passing it to php?